# Dynamically putting functions into an object without losing type information

Tags: typescript, types

In my functions.ts, I define 2 functions, both take an `api` object, and returns a function with different arg types, arg numbers and return types.

```
export function f1 (api: Api) {
  return function (a: number): number[] {/* not important */}
};
export function f2 (api: Api) {
  return function (a: string, b: string): boolean {/* not important */}
};
```

Now given an `api: Api` global object, I want to define an object, that has fields `f1` and `f2`, and the value associated to each field is the inner function inside the above 2 functions.

Namely, manually, I would do:

```
const api: Api = ...;
const myObject = {
  f1: f1(api),
  f2: f2(api),
}
```

And this works super well.

But the next step: I wish to do it **dynamically**, i.e. without manually typing f1 and f2.

Here's my start:

```
import * as functions from './functions';

const api: Api = ...;
const myObject = Object.keys(functions).reduce((accumulator, functionName) => {
  accumulator[functionName] = functions[functionName](api);
}, {} as ???);
```

The code works, but the typings don't. I'm not sure what to put instead of `???`. `{[index: keyof typeof functions]: (...args: any[]) => any}` would work, but I lose a lot of information on types.

I tried looking at TS's `Parameters<T>`, `ReturnType<T>` and I'm sure there's something to be done with `infer`, but can't seem to get hold of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code works, but the typings don't. I'm not sure what to put instead of ???.

Here is an approach that works. It creates a new type that maps each function name to its return type.

```
type ReturnTypes<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any
    ? ReturnType<T[K]>
    : never;
};

const myObject = Object
    .keys(functions)
    .reduce(
        (accumulator, functionName) => {
            accumulator[functionName] = functions[functionName](api);
            return accumulator;
        },
        {} as ReturnTypes<typeof functions>
    );

const result1: number[] = myObject.f1(10);
const result2: boolean = myObject.f2('foo', 'bar');
```

Here it is in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Api%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f1(api%3A%20Api)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f2(api%3A%20Api)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%20return%20true%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20mimic%20the%20import%20of%20a%20module%20with%20two%20named%20exports%0D%0Aconst%20functions%20%3D%20%7B%20f1%2C%20f2%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReturnTypes%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20ReturnType%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20api%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myObject%20%3D%20Object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.keys(functions)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(accumulator%2C%20functionName)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20accumulator%5BfunctionName%5D%20%3D%20functions%5BfunctionName%5D(api)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20accumulator%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7D%20as%20ReturnTypes%3Ctypeof%20functions%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result1%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20myObject.f1(10)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20result2%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20myObject.f2('foo'%2C%20'bar')%3B).

Comment: Nice! Could you fix the playground link, I'll have a look

Comment: Playground link fixed.